# How to find the GCD(Greatest common Divisor) of the numbers given as algebraic expressions

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I am not able to establish that the GCD will not depend upon the value of $n$. Although by taking some initial values of $n$, the GCD is always 1, how do we prove that it is always 1 whatever be the value of $n$.

Comment: Let $a=22n+1$ and $b=33n+2$. What is $3a-2b$?

Comment: Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. For example "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: And your questions will be better received in this forum if you use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to type the math expressions. Some users don't even read your question if it's not properly formated.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote the numbers by $A$ and $B$, where

$A=22n+1$

$B=33n+2$

Our first task is to establish a relation between $A$ and $B$ such that $n$ is eliminated.

$3A=66n+3$ and $2B=66n+4$

$\Rightarrow 2B-3A=1$

Now suppose GCD of $A,\,\,B$ is $k$, then $2B-3A$should be a multiple of $k$, but we have just proved that $2B-3A=1$, therefore $k=1$ only.

Comment: Is it also required that the multipliers chosen to create the relationship be co-prime?  Using 33 and 22 as the multipliers, for example,  would eliminate n and leave a difference of 11

Comment: Yes. If multipliers are not co-primes, then the cosntant in the right hand side of the equation will never be 1.

Comment: @Anil Sharma Why don't you apply plainly [Bezout identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) ?